# Node.js открыть ярлык(.lnk) | Node .js execute .lnk

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

Возникла проблема, при открытии ярлыка(.lnk) через node.js. Подскажите, как открывать ярлыки(.lnk) через node.js. Спасибо.

Прилагаю код:

```js
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

var runLibreOffice =function(){
    exec('D:\\Downloads\\bot\\botgo.lnk', function(err, data) {
        console.log(err)
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
}
runLibreOffice();
```

Comment: `exec('D:\\Downloads\\bot\\botgo.lnk', {shell : true}, function(err, data) {...`, либо  `var exec = require('child_process').exec;`

Comment: Данное сообщение получаю:

D:\Work\Script>node controller.js
{ Error: Command failed: D:\Downloads\bot\botgo.lnk
���⥬� �� 㤠���� ���� 㪠����� ����.

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:289:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd:
   'D:\\Downloads\\bot\\botgo.lnk' }

Comment: А сам .lnk-файл-то корректный? Даблкликом из проводника открывается нормально?

Comment: Да, работает корректно.

Comment: Любопытно, у меня работает нормально. Не знаю, в чем еще может быть дело. :( Хорошо бы как-то получить в удобочитаемой кодировке текст, превратившийся в ��... Может, там будет какая-то подсказка.

Comment: Мне тоже любопытно, но получить пока не удалось.

Answer (score -2):

Проблема решена, путём добавления {shell : true} в аргументы функции и пересозданием ярлыка.

Код:

```js
spawn('D:\\Downloads\\bot\\botgo.lnk', {shell : true}, function(err, data)
```

Comment: Напишите в ответ итоговый код